# Create a class from an interface and a method to use an object as a string

Tags: java

I have a problem in java that I have trouble solving:
Create a **KeyValImpl** class that respects the **KeyVal** interface.
Write the code of the **add ()** method so that it stores the index and the value
which are passed to it as parameters and that of the **get ()** method so that it returns
the value corresponding to the index which is passed to it as a parameter.

Construct the class such that when used as a string,
it returns what it contains in the following format:

```
key1: val1, key2: val2, key3: val3
```

The order of the returned items is not important but all items must be returned in this
exact format.
Here is the code to complete:

```
public class ExerciseImpl {

// Here are examples of calling methods of a KeyValImpl object
     // as well as a call of the object itself as a character string.
    
    
    public void runExercise (String [] argv) throws Exception {

        KeyValImpl keyVal = new KeyValImpl ();
        keyVal.add ("apples", "12");
        keyVal.add ("pears", "11");
        keyVal.add ("oranges", "13");
        System.out.println ("<pre>");
        System.out.println (keyVal.get ("oranges"));
        System.out.println (keyVal);
        System.out.println ("</pre>");
    }

}

KeyVal interface {

    
    public void add (String key, String val);
    public String get (String key);
}

/ * ---------- DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE ABOVE THIS LINE, IT WILL BE RESET ON RUN ---------- * /


/ *** Enter your code here *** /

    / * ---------- DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW THIS LINE, IT WILL BE RESET WHEN RUNNING ---------- * /

}
```

Here is the code I came up with:

```
 public class ExerciseImpl {

   // Here are examples of calling methods of a KeyValImpl object
     // as well as a call of the object itself as a character string.
    
    public void runExercise (String [] argv) throws Exception {
   

        KeyValImpl keyVal = new KeyValImpl ();
        keyVal.add ("apples", "12");
        keyVal.add ("pears", "11");
        keyVal.add ("oranges", "13");
        System.out.println ("<pre>");
        System.out.println (keyVal.get ("oranges"));
        System.out.println (keyVal);
        System.out.println ("</pre>");
    }

}

KeyVal interface {
    public void add (String key, String val);
    public String get (String key);
}

/ * ---------- DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE ABOVE THIS LINE, IT WILL BE RESET ON RUN ---------- * /


class KeyValImpl KeyVal implements {




}
    public void add (String key, String val) {

    }
    public String get (String key) {
        return key;
    }

    / * ---------- DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW THIS LINE, IT WILL BE RESET WHEN RUNNING ---------- * /

}
```

I know this is not correct but I don't know how to translate the following sentence
in java code:
"Create a class  **KeyValImpl**  which  **respects**  the interface  **KeyVal** ", first a class which  **respects**
an interface, I don't know what that means, for me  **respecting**  an interface is implementing the interface
Am I Right?
Then, I have to write the code of the **add ()** method so that it  **stores** the index and the value  which are passed to it as a parameter.
How do I translate the sentence: " **store index and value** " in java code?  **store**  index and value, I don't know
how to express it in java code.
Then the last part: "Build the class such that when used as a string,
it returns what it contains in the following format:
*key1: val1* , *key2: val2* ,  *key3: val3*  .", I don't know how to express it in java code.

Do you have any ideas for me ?

Comment: `class KeyValImpl extends HashMap<String,String> implements KeyVal {}`

Comment: ok i understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class KeyValImpl implements KeyVal {
    private final Map<String, String> map;

    public KeyValImpl() {
        map = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void add(String key, String val) {
        map.put(key, val);
    }

    @Override
    public String get(String key) {
        return map.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if (sb.length() > 0)
                sb.append(", ");
            sb.append(entry.getKey());
            sb.append(": ");
            sb.append(entry.getValue());
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

You could use a HashMap for this problem.
And yeah it means you should implement the interface.
I think that it means with 'Used as a string' that you should implement the 'toString' method?! Because you can't override / extend the String class, so making your own String class is not really an option (You could make a CharSequence though ;) )

Edit:

In your run exercise method there is this line:

```
System.out.println(keyVal);
```

This actually calls .toString() on the provided object. So what that means is that you should not only implement the methods of the interface, but also the method 'toString()' (As I did for you)

Hope this helps you!

Comment: thanks , so i should use a map,i will compile and test the code,thanks

Comment: You can use a map, or if your teacher or whatever whats you to implement it yourself use the other implementation I provided later (I added two answers for your question). It will do almost the same (except that key can appear twice in the list, if you add the two times)

Comment: Thanks,it works,you nailed it,in fact i complied and test it and i get the exact return in this format:key1:val1,key2:val2,key3:val3.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have basically been asked to implement a Map. You need only a minor tweak to the extension of an existing class to get the job done:

```
class KeyValImpl extends LinkedHashMap<String, String> implements KeyVal {
    public void add(String key, String value) {
        put(key, value);
    }
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString().replaceAll("^.|.$", "").replace("=", ": ");
    }
}
```

`LinkedHashMap` does all the heavy lifting (once `add()` delegates to `put()`), particularly its `toString()` method which has keys and values in order of insertion, needing only the first and last characters of its implantation (which are curly brackets) to be removed and equals signs changed to colons.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class KeyValImpl implements KeyVal {
    private String[][] map;
    private int len, cap;

    public KeyValImpl() {
        this(5);
    }

    public KeyValImpl(int cap) {
        this.map = new String[cap][];
        this.len = 0;
        this.cap = cap;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(String key, String val) {
        if (len >= cap) {
            int nextCap = cap * 2;
            String[][] nextMap = new String[nextCap][];
            System.arraycopy(map, 0, nextMap, 0, cap);
            map = nextMap;
            cap = nextCap;
        }

        map[len++] = new String[] {key, val};
    }

    @Override
    public String get(String key) {
        int i = 0;
        for (; i < len; i++) {
            String[] entry = map[i];
            if (entry[0] != null && entry[0].equals(key))
                break;
        }
        return i < len ? map[i][1] : null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            String[] entry = map[i];

            if (sb.length() > 0)
                sb.append(", ");
            sb.append(entry[0]);
            sb.append(": ");
            sb.append(entry[1]);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

If you are not allowed to use HashMap like I did earlier than use this.
This is how it works in the background.
(Note: This implementation also allows for the same key to exists twice.)